# not able to select option in a dropdown using select in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have an drop down code with following options :

```
<select class="col-10 customDropdown focusOutVal xh-highlight" id="SourceOfIncome" name="PrimaryIncome.SourceOfIncome" sb="59436885" style="display: none;"><option value="" class="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="Employed1" class="">Employed1</option>
<option value="Employed2" class="">Employed2</option>
<option selected="Employed3" value="Employed3" class="">Employed3</option>
<option value="Employed4" class="" selected="selected">Employed4</option>
<option value="Employed5" class="">Employed5</option>
<option value="Employed6" class="">Employed6</option>
<option value="Other" class="">Other*</option>
</select>
```

I wrote following code to find print all the options :

I am getting same value for all the elements and when I am selecting a particular element using visible-text option , its giving ElementnotVisibleException.

Comment: Can you add the code?

Answer (score 0):

ok, firstly in code, there should not be "display:none" in code. you can modify the code as ->style="display:;">

if you creating the html by yourself or the droop down is showing in another way. Secondly, for print all the options

List(WebElement) allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.id("SourceOfIncome"));
for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions)
{System.out.println(suggestion.getText());}

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that it is an wait issue as you mentioned "ElementnotVisibleException". Considering you have not introduced WebDriverWait in your code, try following

```
Select sel = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SourceOfIncome"))));
    List<WebElement> options = sel.getOptions();
    Iterator<WebElement> optionItr = options.iterator();
    while(optionItr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(optionItr.next().getText());
    }
```